# How does one get another torch once it runs out?

Tags: dark-souls-2

Stumbled into the gutter via the well in Majula and my torch ran out.
Where and how can I get another torch to light?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Torches are dropped by certain enemies, and can also be found in fixed locations in the game world (from chests, corpses, et cetera). Every Torch you find will add 5 minutes to your torch timer, located inside the equipment menu. Torch wielding enemies seem to have a high chance of dropping a torch, and there are a few of them located inside the gutter. You can proceed through The Gutter just fine without a torch, so I wouldn't bother  backtracking to try and get another torch.

Comment: Thanks, i don't seem to find the torch anywhere in my inventory, other than a timer showing time left in the player stats screen. Does this just increase by x seconds every time i pick up a new torch or is there anywhere else i can see how many torches i have.

Comment: @Timmah: Finding a torch will just increase the timer by 5 minutes. There's no torch item which shows up in your inventory.

Comment: Tip: If you're low on torches, only light it to run straight to a new sconse/brazier and put it out again asap. Sucks when you drop into another level though..